# Is it possible to move part of app's logic to server-side and use it by UIWebView in app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

I want to move Cart part from my app (shop's catalog) to server side (server version has full-featured Cart) and show it in app by UIWebView as iframe. So, I'm interesting, may it be rejected? I've read some similar questions such as [is it possible to use iframe in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167907/is-it-possible-to-use-iframe-in-uiwebview) but in my case it's not a "simple fb button", but big part with logic, graphic etc

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fine as all Cordova/Phonegap/other hybrid frameworks are using entirely `UIWebView`. The only thing you'll need to take care of seems to be handling the offline situations gracefully...